# How is this fixed bottom bar on the UITableView implemented

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I was watching a video from WWDC 2015, in which the presenter showcased a table view that has a fixed bar at the bottom, and he put a progress bar and some label in it. The video is about on-demand resources, so he didn't go into detail on how the bar is implemented. But I'm genuinely intrigued on how it's implemented:

The view's controller is a subclass of UITableViewController, so the root view of that controller must be a table view. As far as I know, there is no clean way to fix some UI view inside a table view.

It doesn't look like a toolbar from the navigation controller either, since the label is at the center and the progress bar is across the whole bar. I think you can only put discrete buttons inside the toolbar? Maybe that's not the case, but the from the size of that table view controller, it seems he didn't write much code to implement it.

I wonder how is this bottom bar implemented? You can see it [at this moment of the video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-214/?time=1419).

(I wonder if it's legal to paste a screenshot of WWDC video here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't resist the curiosity, and I sent an email to Tony Parker (the speaker) asking for help. He was kind enough to send me the source code of iTravel. Now I know how it's implemented in the storyboard.

The trick is that you need to create a docked view in the controller (i.e. put a regular UIView in the scene dock), put the text and the progress bar in it, and layout them using auto layout.

Then in the table view controller, add this method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: animated)

    overallView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(overallView!)

    self.navigationController?.toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (overallView?.leadingAnchor)!).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (overallView?.trailingAnchor)!).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (overallView?.topAnchor)!).isActive = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (overallView?.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

where `overallView` is the docked UIView outlet.

Credit goes to the author of the iTravel app (most likely Tony Parker).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it looks a lot like it's using the toolbar provided by the navigation controller.

You can add custom views to toolbars and you can center items using the flexible space item. Here is how to do it in just a few lines :

```
// In your tabble view controller subclass
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44.0))
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "Hello world!"
    let toolBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.setToolbarItems([flexibleSpace, toolBarItem, flexibleSpace], animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

    let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
    progressView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 2.0)
    progressView.trackTintColor = .lightGray
    progressView.progress = 0.5
    self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(progressView)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and it looks a lot like what's in that video. However, the presenter mentioned it's [hooked up in a storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-214/?time=1346). Do you think these views inside the toolbar can be constructed from a storyboard?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in Interface Builder, but I could be wrong (I don't use storyboards much)